# Using Like with variables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an odd situation where I have a column called (TransmittalNumber) with datatype of VarChar (75) in a table named (Transmittal Sheet).

I want to query this table to find the transmittal numbers that are duplicated or the ones that starts with the same numbers but ends with a suffix of –W for (West division). Please check the TS# column below:

```
TSID    TS #    Facility
1    1234       Arizona
2    1234 -W      National
3    2222       Pacif.NW
4    2222 -W      National
5    4444       California
6    4444 -W      National
7    5555        Arizona
8    5555        Arizona
```

Would something like the following query works?:

```
declare @TSNumber varchar(75)


set @TSNumber = (select transmittalnumber from TransmittalSheet
)
-   Subquery above returned more than 1 value even with using the IN!
SELECT     TransmittalID, TransmittalNumber, Facility 
FROM         TransmittalSheet ts
where  ts.TransmittalNumber like (@TSNumber) 

union all 

SELECT     TransmittalID, TransmittalNumber, Facility
FROM         TransmittalSheet ts1
where ts1.transmittalnumber like (@TSNumber + '-w')
```

Prior to 2014, the numbers entered to this column were only added from local regions. Now all TS numbers are entered from a National side, so the older similar local TSs will have –W in the new national entry after a migrate.

The reason of my query now is to clean up the table from the local ones that still have a current active entry in the national.

I've tried a self join with no luck still, any advice?

```
SELECT ts.TransmittalNumber from TransmittalSheet ts
Full Join TransmittalSheet ts2 
ON ts.TransmittalID = ts2.TransmittalID
-- AND 
WHERE ts.TransmittalNumber = ts2.TransmittalNumber + ' -W'
```

I’m using the SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Your queries have 5 columns, the data 3. The column names do not match. How do you expect people to understand the issue?

Comment: Also, is it possible that there are MORE than two rows that match (e.g. is `TS #` unique?

Comment: I meant to only show a sample data and I wanted the focus to be on the TS#, but I will omit the other columns if its confusing. Thank you

Comment: No its not unique, and that's why I wanted to find which local facility entered the duplicate ones, so I do have few transmittal numbers that can be the same but with different IDs, as the TransmittalID is the only unique column in that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This applies the same matching logic as Aaron Bertrand to a Windowed Aggregate Function:

```
;WITH dt AS 
(
  SELECT tab.*,
    COUNT(*) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY [TS #] + CASE WHEN [TS #] NOT LIKE '% -W' THEN ' -W' ELSE '' END) AS cnt
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM dt 
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e486d/6)

**Edit:**

As `[TS #]` is not unique, the above will not work and `DISTINCT` is not allowed in Windowed Aggregate Functions...

So this uses a modified logic: If MIN and MAX are different, both versions exist:

```
;WITH dt AS 
(
  SELECT tab.*,
    MIN([TS #]) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY [TS #] + CASE WHEN [TS #] NOT LIKE '% -W' THEN ' -W' ELSE '' END) AS minTS,
    MAX([TS #]) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY [TS #] + CASE WHEN [TS #] NOT LIKE '% -W' THEN ' -W' ELSE '' END) AS maxTS
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM dt 
WHERE minTS <> maxTS;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71481/1)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I don't see Aaron's code for some reason, I think I will understand your answer above better as soon as he re-post something back. I really appreciate you guys helping me.

Comment: I finally saw the Fiddle link in your post, this is really neat to be able to run the SQL queries there for us! could you just explain how is the CASE statement is getting the results?
Are you saying that When [TS#] doesn't contain the -W, then giving me the ones that ends with -W ELSE do nothing?
 I think I'm not understanding that part with the NOT LIKE part, please advice. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mary:  When [TS#] doesn't contain the ' -W', then ' -W' is concatenated to it. This bit was stolen from Aaron Bertrand, I don't know why he deleted his answer. But this query (and Aaron's) will fail when `TS #` is not unique, I'll modify it to work with duplicates, too.

Comment: I needed to see both in the result set (the ones with -W and the ones without -W for the same TS numbers), that's why maybe I didn't understand why you are concatenating the -W to the ones that don't have the -W in the CASE statement. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Mary: You'll see both (the ones with -W and the ones without -W for the same TS numbers), the concat is just within the PARTITION BY, but that values are still the same...

Comment: Thank you very much, your Min and Max query solved it for me!
One day, hopefully I will understand the Windowed Aggregate Functions better, Thank you guys for introducing me to it. Although I still think that even though my [TS#] column is not explicitly specified to be unique, the values look unique to me as they have the -W for the ones that starts with the same numbers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your data follows a strict pattern:
If there is more than one entry like #TS%, then the first entry will be the one with #TS, the second will be the one with #TS - W. Obviously, if you sort descending, the order will be reversed.

Therefore the solution seems obvious: group by #TS, get those lines where row_number >1, when sorted descending.

```
SELECT     * , row_number() over (partition by left(TransmittalNumber,4) as RN order by TransmittalNumber DESC)
FROM         TransmittalSheet ts
```

To get only the multiples, you'd put that into a CTE:

```
With T1 as (SELECT     * , row_number() over (partition by left(TransmittalNumber,4) as RN order by TransmittalNumber DESC)
    FROM         TransmittalSheet ts)
select * from T1 where T1.RN>1
```

You could then simply inner join that CTE to your original table on TransmittalID to remove all duplicates.

If the TransmittalNumber has a variable length, you'd also have to use patindex(), in order to calculate your parameter for the left() function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think your answer is what I'm looking for as I want to see the 1st entry to be the one with TS#, the 2nd will be the one with TS# -W.
 As soon as I educate myself more about CTE and row_number function, I will test your code as I never used them. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want the first entry to be TS# without -w, you'd order ASC instead of DESC, but as far as i understood, you wanted to remove duplicates and if there's a record with and without -w, you wanted to keep the one WITH -w?

Comment: I'm also not quite sure about the Arizona duplicate in your example. Do you want to get rid of that duplicate or keep it?

Comment: I couldn't get the patindex() to work with your CTE query correctly, as you are right the [TS#] has a variable lenght, that's why I chose the above answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes I'm removing the absolute duplicates like the Arizona ones in my example as users entered these exact duplicates by mistake. But for the ones that have -W, I will re-associate the documents (from another table [Documents]) attached to these local TSs  (without the -W) to the national ones that have the -W. so we are keeping the local ones for historical reasons since our process now is to enter everything from national side only.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you'd use patindex() like this: left(TN,patindex('% %',TN)-1) or alternatively (patindex('% -w')-1) if -w can be attached to a TN that could be anything. charindex(' ', TN) could also work.